# Joomla router.php links displayed correctly but doesnt works joomla 3.7

Tags: joomla, router, joomla3.7

I have a problem with router.php
 I cannot found an error in `public function parse(&$segments)`
The url generated as i want but it doesn't work with sef correct 
the parse function gets correctly the view and the id_tsi parameters but id_tsi parameter seems to be not working

Version of joomla 3.7

the url of the component looks like

`www.ktopoverit.ru/index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=reestr_si&id_tsi=1`

url with switched on sef looks like

```
www.ktopoverit.ru/poverka/reestr_si/1
```

$vars looks like

```
Array (
    [view] => reestr_si 
    [id_tsi] => 1
)
```

and my router is

```
class helloworldRouter extends JComponentRouterBase
{
    public function build(&$query)
    {
        $segments = array();

        if (isset($query['view']))
        {
            $segments[] = $query['view'];
            unset($query['view']);
        }

        if (isset($query['id_tsi']))
        {
            $segments[] = $query['id_tsi'];
            unset($query['id_tsi']);
        };

        return $segments;
    }

    public function parse(&$segments)
    {
        $vars = array();

        switch($segments[0])
        {
            case 'reestr_si':
                $vars['view'] = 'reestr_si';
                $id = explode(':', $segments[0]);
                $vars['id_tsi'] = (int) $id[1];
                break;
        }

        return $vars;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `build()` method creates the right URLs, it makes sense to take it as the base for some assumptions.

`$query` contains max. two values, a view (`string`) and an id (`int`). One or both of them may be omitted.

So. independent from the actual number of segments, we can just assume that an `int` represents the id and a `string` (i.e., everything else) represents the view.

```
/**
 * Parse URL
 *
 * This method is meant to transform the human readable URL back into
 * query parameters. It is only executed when SEF mode is switched on.
 *
 * @param   array  &$segments  The segments of the URL to parse.
 *
 * @return  array  The URL attributes to be used by the application.
 */
public function parse(&$segments)
{
    while (!empty($segments))
    {
        $segment = array_pop($segments);

        if (is_numeric($segment))
        {
            // It's the ID
            $vars['id_tsi'] = (int) $segment;
        }
        else
        {
            // It's the view
            $vars['view'] = $segment;
        }
    }

    return $vars;
}
```